# Cannot rotate second monitor with xrandr (Nvidia VGA): cannot use rotation "left" reflection "none"

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, xrandr

I've got an Ubuntu 15.10 laptop with an integrated intel VGA and a Nvidia Geforce gtx 960m

```
lspci -nn | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:191b] (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] [10de:139b] (rev a2)
```

I also have a second monitor which is able to rotate, but I'm not able to rotate the screeen using xrandr command:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1-1 --rotate left
xrandr: output HDMI-1-1 cannot use rotation "left" reflection "none"
```

This is my xorg.conf file, I've already added **Option "RandRRotation" "True"**, but nothing changes

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "modesetting"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "None"
    Option "RandRRotation" "True"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
    Option "RandRRotation" "True"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
EndSection
```

I've added randrrotation in both VGAs, but if I add the option only on Nvidia Device section, nothing changes anyway.

Anyone can help me, please?

Comment: same problem with the GM108M [GeForce 940M]