# Rotation/reflection of built-in monitor disables external monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have a laptop (Dell Latitude series) with an external monitor attached to it via HDMI, running Ubuntu 18.04.04. The graphics card is Intel UHD 620. I am trying to achieve that the built-in display of the laptop (eDP-1) is reflected in the x-axis, while the external monitor (HDMI-1) is not reflected (for an autocue set-up).

Using xrandr, I believe the following should work, however even though it reflects the built-in monitor, it also disables the external monitor altogether (which turns off).

```
xrandr \
    --output eDP-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --reflect x \
    --output HDMI-1 --primary --mode 2560x1440 --pos 1920x0 --reflect normal \
    --output DP-1 --off \
    --output HDMI-2 --off \
    --output DP-2 --off
```

The following variation works as expected (both monitors not reflected):

```
xrandr \
    --output eDP-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --reflect normal \
    --output HDMI-1 --primary --mode 2560x1440 --pos 1920x0 --reflect normal \
    --output DP-1 --off \
    --output HDMI-2 --off \
    --output DP-2 --off
```

The following variation that reflects only the external monitor also works without issue:

```
xrandr \
    --output eDP-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --reflect normal \
    --output HDMI-1 --primary --mode 2560x1440 --pos 1920x0 --reflect x \
    --output DP-1 --off \
    --output HDMI-2 --off \
    --output DP-2 --off
```

So, in summary, I can reflect each of the monitors, however if I reflect the built-in monitor then the external monitor turns off.
It seems related to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/753407/cannot-rotate-second-monitor-with-xrandr-nvidia-vga-cannot-use-rotation-left), however to that no answer was provided.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Should be 18.04, the most recent LTS release. Updated the question, thanks :)